# Trying to find the exact word in the command line arguments using bash script

Tags: bash

I am accepting user input and want the script to work for below cases. I have tried using '==' and '=~'. However my script works well for the second case when I use '==' but first one fails. When I use the '=~' instead the script accepts arguments like ./script john harryyy smith.. which I don't want it to accept. Any best way to get both cases working?

1. `./script john harry smith`
2. `./script john`

---

```
if [[ "${args[@]}" == "john" ]]; then
....
else
....
```

Comment: Define "working". What do you want to happen?

Comment: Script must accept the user input and accept the exact word harry. User input could be a long list. Any misspelled word like harryyy should be ignored

Comment: To explain the basic problem here: if `args` is the array "john", "harry", smith", then `if [[ "${args[@]}" == "john" ]]` is essentially `[[ "john harry smith" == "john" ]]`, which of course does not match. You don't want to compare the array, you want to compare each individual element of the array. Also, how is `args` defined? It's easy to copy the script's arguments into an array, but it's also easy to get it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `grep`, and then `wc` to count the grep matches.

```
if [[ "$(echo ${args[@]} | grep "john" | wc -l) -ge 0 ]]; then ...; else...; fi
```

For user input, I'd recommend using `grep -i`, to make the grep search case insensitive.

**Edit:**

Didn't fully read the whole question, so my bad there. The above will still match harry to harryyy. For matching multiple arguments to multiple variables, I would probably use for loops.

```
for ((i=0;i<${#args[@]};i++)); do
    if [ ${args[$i]} = "john" ]; then
        ...
        break #optional, prevents the code from executing twice if the user has typed two "john"s.
    fi
done
```

Of couse, you'd have to have a loop for each name you wanted to check. If you put the names into an array as well, you could double-loop instead;

```
#array names contains the names to check against.
for ((i=0;i<${#names[@]};i++)); do
    for ((ii=0;ii<${#args[@]};ii++)); do
        if [ ${args[$ii]} = ${names[$i]} ]; then
            ...
            continue 2 #again, optional, continues the first loop for the same reason as above
        fi
    done
done
```

Comment: I'd iterate over the array elements, instead of the indexes. Something like `for arg in "${args[@]}"; do ... if [[ "$arg" = ...`

Comment: @GordonDavisson

Comment: Note to self, enter is not a new line in the comments field... Anyway, @GordonDavisson, I've never thought of doing it like that, guess I've never needed to. I imagine it would work better especially if there's a chance of elements being deleted or added at wierd indexes. One question, though. Not that it really matters in this example, since each element comes from an argument, but something like for arg in "${args[@]}" would have issues if an element had spaces, correct? For an array of 0=foo;1=bar;2=foo and bar, you'd end up looping for "foo, bar, foo, and, bar", right?

Comment: No, as long as you have double-quotes around it (`"${args[@]}"`), it skips the usual word splitting (and wildcard expansion), but the `[@]` makes it expand each array element as a separate word (unlike `[*]`, which mushes them all together). Note that the usage in the original question is an exception to this -- inside `[[ ]]`, expansion into multiple words is not allowed, so `[@]` acts like `[*]`.

Comment: BTW, you can delete your comments if they don't come out right (not that that ever happens to me) (whistles innocently) -- if you mouse over them, a little "x" should appear after the attribution and time.

Answer (score 0):

I think i would use case statement something like this .. this is not exact code. This seems to work as i am particularly looking for a string like 'john'

case ${args[i]} in
        'harry'|'smith'|.....)
         .....
         ......
         ;;

```
    'john')
     .....
     .......
      ;;

    *)
```